# Override magento model files getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: error-handling, model, module, extend, magento-1.9

I need to edit the below file

> /var/www/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php

i dont want to edit the core file

for which i have done this so far

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Coreextended>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Inchoo_Coreextended_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

i have created the folowing directory from where i like to extend the file

/var/www/magento1.9/app/code/local/Inchoo/Coreextended/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php

and file is as

```
class Inchoo_Coreextended_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey_Abstract
{

}
```

but when I am going to catalog pages i get following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Inchoo_Coreextended_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey::setStoreId() in /var/www/magento1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php on line 66

please suggest where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 0):

change your config.xml code 
from

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>Inchoo_Coreextended_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey</product>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

to

```
<global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_attribute_backend_urlkey>Inchoo_Coreextended_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey</product_attribute_backend_urlkey>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
```